# What is the state of smach_viewer in ROS Jade?

Tags: ros-jade, smach, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know when and in what form the smach viewer utility will be released for jade.

The indigo release has the packages ros-indigo-smach-viewer and ros-indigo-xdot, but there are no such packages for jade. Downloading the smach_viewer source code to my ros workspace shows that smach_viewer depends on the package xdot, but xdot was deprecated during the ros groovy release, yet was still released in hydro and indigo. Searching around shows some talk a few years ago about xdot being replaced with [rqt_dotgraph](http://wiki.ros.org/qt_gui_core), but I haven't found anything besides a broken link.

What's the state of smach_viewer in ROS Jade? Will the old xdot and smach_viewer packages be released in jade? Will an rqt version be ready for jade?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215313/what-is-the-state-of-smach_viewer-in-ros-jade?/) by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3061 on 2015-08-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The interim solution I found was to get xdot package from the following link: http://wiki.ros.org/xdot.

When you do $ git clone https://github.com/ros-visualization/rx.git (branch: groovy-devel) you will get folder "rx".
You will need to take only "xdot" folder (inside the "rx" folder) and place it in your workspace, then do catkin_make.

Now you should be able to do $ rosrun smach_viewer smach_viewer.py.

You may get the following error message after you run smach_viewer:

File "/home/kt1e11/catkin_ws/src/xdot/src/xdot/xdot.py", line 480, in read_number
return int(self.read_code())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

In that cast, you can just replace return int(self.read_code()) wit return int(float(self.read_code()))

---

Originally posted by [kantapon](https://answers.ros.org/users/24386/kantapon/) with karma: 26 on 2015-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2015-10-15**:
Thank you, this solution works perfectly. Hopefully an official release will come soon!